# Unable to download images with excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this code to download images with excel and rename files, but all of sudden the size of the downloaded file is coming 1.47 kb and the file is not readable.

Can you help where i am going wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
FolderName = Range("$B$2").Value
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Error"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in other site: Try investigating the downloaded file using some text editor, Notepad, for example. Maybe, instead of a JPG file, you will see in "filename.jpg" a text or HTML containing some error message!, perhaps related to security stuffs (in my case, Google was asking for login in google to download the file). Maybe the file is not publicly available, and you cannot download it using your code because Google expects a password.